# In SQL Server, what's the best way to split multiple delimited strings into rows without a function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I know there are numerous examples of how to split strings in SQL Server. However, they are often for a single delimited string. What's the best way to split multiple delimited strings without using a function (SQL Server 2016)?

Here's what I'm starting with:

```
GroupId     Val1      Val2
----------- --------- ------
G1           1,2,3     a,b,c
G2           4,5,6     d,e,f
G3           1,2,3,4   w,x,y,z
```

Here's what I would like to end up with:

```
GroupId Val1    Val2
------- ------- -------
G1      1       a
G1      2       b
G1      3       c
G2      4       d
G2      5       e
G2      6       f
G3      1       w
G3      2       x
G3      3       y      
G3      4       z
```

Based on everything I've read, I *think* I may need to use the XML method because it allows me to specify an order, but I haven't been able to find an example of this method where multiple columns are split.

Here's the T-SQL to create the source table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData(GroupId VARCHAR(10),
                       Val1 VARCHAR(100),
                       Val2 VARCHAR(100)
                       );
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES ('G1', '1,2,3', 'a,b,c'),
       ('G2', '4,5,6', 'd,e,f'),
       ('G3', '1,2,3,4', 'w,x,y,z');

SELECT *
FROM #TestData;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @McNets Yes they will always be consistent with one another but the number may be different between Group Ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the delimited string to a JSON array, and use OPENJSON, which exposes the lexical ordering for arrays.  eg

This

```
select *
from openjson('["w","x","y","z"]')
```

outputs

```
key       value  
--------- -------
0         w      
1         x      
2         y      
3         z
```

So

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData(GroupId VARCHAR(10),
                       Val1 VARCHAR(100),
                       Val2 VARCHAR(100)
                       );
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES ('G1', '1,2,3', 'a,b,c'),
       ('G2', '4,5,6', 'd,e,f'),
       ('G3', '1,2,3,4', 'w,x,y,z');

with q as
(
  SELECT GroupId, concat('["',replace(Val1,',','","'),'"]') Val1,concat('["',replace(Val2,',','","'),'"]') Val2
  FROM #TestData
)
select GroupId, v1.value Val1, v2.value Val2
from q
cross apply openjson(Val1) v1
cross apply openjson(Val2) v2
where v1.[key] = v2.[key]
```

outputs

```
GroupId    Val1     Val2
---------- -------- ---------------
G1         1        a
G1         2        b
G1         3        c
G2         4        d
G2         5        e
G2         6        f
G3         1        w
G3         2        x
G3         3        y
G3         4        z
```

Comment: This is so incredibly helpful! Works perfectly and is exactly what I needed. Thank you both!

Comment: Also, @erik-darling, I am using a collation that is case sensitive, so thanks for that edit!